# How can I improve the scan quality of the text written with a pencil?

Tags: scanning

I use a [FUJITSU IX500 Scansnap Document Scanner](https://smile.amazon.com/Fujitsu-Scansnap-Document-Scanner-PA03656-B305-R/dp/B01JZXVNP8). How can I improve the scan quality of the text written with a pencil?

---

Example:

Before scanning:

[image]

After scanning:

[image]

The notes written with a pencil in the header and the footer have a poor quality in the scan.

Comment: If you know someone who has a high-end Samsung phone that has intelligent scanning and a built-in document scanner option in the Camera settings try using the phone as a document scanner. The other advantage besides intelligent scanning is that you can adjust the lighting conditions for optimal contrast until you get a readable scan.

Comment: @karelv Thanks. The issue is I have to scan many pages, so I need to scan several pages at once (i.e., I  can't use a flatbed scanner)

Comment: It still might help to improve the unreadable scans in case you can sort out the a few of the unreadable scans and rescan them using a phone.

Comment: My solution for faint ink is to photo the pages with high contrast, which makes the characters more evident.

Comment: iPhones can do that too, these days. Your scanned image is in monochrome, which means in effect that no further processing can be done to it. It has only two values, black & white. Whatever you do needs to be done in the scanner software, or at least scan in greyscale.

Comment: @Tetsujin: It's not real monochrome. When I convert such text photos to black&white, some characters lose some pieces..

Comment: @karel thanks unfortunately I'm scanning over 1000 pages, I can't really manually single out some pages and anyway likely over half of them have this issue.

Comment: @harrymc - The profile is sRGB, but the image itself is monochrome - blow-up of one handwritten character… https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLipa.png [repost with image attached ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, greyscale fixed the issue, you're welcome to post as an answer!

Comment: Glad you got it - your answer looks far more comprehensive than I could manage, so go for it :)

Comment: If the scanner has grey scale, use that.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the default scanning mode was auto-color detection:

[image]

The auto-color detection must have incorrectly thought that the document was black and white.

Changing it to "gray" fixed this issue:

[image]

[image]

Note that one shouldn't select "reduce bleed-through",  as it would also triggers the issue:

[image]

"Increase text contrast" also triggers the issue, so better left unchecked:

[image]

[image]

Increasing DPI doesn't seem to help improve the scan quality of the text written with a pencil. E.g., at 150 DPI:

[image]

vs. at 300 DPI:

[image]

However, increasing DPI does help to improve the scan quality of the printed text. E.g., at 150 DPI:

[image]

vs. at 300 DPI:

[image]

---

In summary, the following settings seem optimal to scan printed documents containing some text written with a pencil (e.g., course notes with annotations):

[image]

[image]